# Issue with an Outer JOIN

Tags: sql, ms-access, outer-join

I am trying to find an alternative to a NOT IN query by using an outer join. I am trying to find the details of the employee who hasn't done any car service.

My NOT IN example looks like this

```
SELECT Employee.EmployeeID, Employee.FirstName, Employee.LastName, Employee.Salary, Employee.[EmployeeID]
FROM Employee
WHERE (((Employee.[EmployeeID]) Not In (SELECT EmployeeID from Service)));
```

My Outer Join draft works however it shows the complete opposite of what I want (i.e. it shows the details of the employees who HAVE done a service)

```
SELECT E.EmployeeId, E.FirstName, E.LastName, E.Salary
FROM Employee AS E
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Service AS S
ON E.EmployeeId = S.EmployeeId
GROUP BY E.EmployeeId, E.FirstName, E.LastName, E.Salary;
```

Any help would be much appreciated
Thanks

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` and `WHERE IS NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  SELECT E.EmployeeId, E.FirstName, E.LastName, E.Salary
    FROM Employee AS E
    LEFT JOIN Service AS S ON E.EmployeeId = S.EmployeeId
    WHERE S.EmployeeID is NULL
    GROUP BY E.EmployeeId, E.FirstName, E.LastName, E.Salary;
```

- `SELECT <fields> FROM Employee` - all employees are chosen
- `LEFT JOIN Service`             - also, find all service records per employee

However, the LEFT JOIN says that if an employee doesn't have a matching service record, bring back a service row anyway, but fill all of the fields with NULL.    If you add S.EmployeeID to your list of fields and remove the WHERE, you will see this.   Some rows will have NULL S.EmployeeID's and others will have S.EmployeeID's with values.    The NULLS are rows where no record was found, but the LEFT JOIN add the column as NULL.

The WHERE clause tells us to only return those records where the S.EmployeeId is NULL, which occurs when no matching Service record was found

Comment: Could you please explain why this works instead of my original @sparky?

Comment: I revised my answer to provide a description

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following should work:

```
WHERE S.EmployeeID is null
```

with a `left join` instead of `right`.

Comment: Not enough. Two changes are required.

Comment: @PM77-1 What I put is no different than the accepted answer, I just didn't put all the code and instead just mentioned it needs to use a left join. The down vote without actually reading the full answer is pretty rude